# Do I have to set each activity in the manifest to lock the orientation or can I do it for the entire app?

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-orientation

I guess this is really two questions: Can I lock all activities in Portrait mode??

Better yet, how do I get all activities to work in either mode?? Does there have to be 2 separate layout files, one for landscape and one for portrait??

I am relatively new, so sorry if this is a rookie question.

Answer (score 0):

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` will work for one actvitiy you can add that for all the activities you need

```
<activity android:name=".Activityname" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can lock all activities in portrait mode by using following tag in manifest. You need to do for every activity.

```
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

If you want your app work in both modes you can achieve this either way.

1. Use two layout (landscape/portrait)
2. Use single layout file and make designs responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain both landscape and portrait mode in your application, you should create separate files for your layouts like this:

```
YourProject/
res/
    layout/              # default (portrait) view
        main.xml
    layout-land/         # landscape view
        main.xml
```

If you do not have a "layout-land" folder, you should create it. Hope this helps you :)

P.S. for more information you could take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) from the Official Android Developers Documentation